# How to use functions to assign variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, variable-assignment

I want to create a structure and then use functions to assign various attributes.  For example, I have the following code:

```
global car


function f1(x)
car.color = x;
end

function f2(x)
car.make = x;
end
```

Why doesn't this work? I don't need the functions to return anything, I just need them to assign the attributes.

edit:

someone suggested the following, but when I input that last "car" command I still get all empty attributes back:

```
car = struct('make',[],'model',[],'color',[],'year',[]);
% 
    function y = test1(x)
        car(1).color = x;
        y = car;
    end
% 
    function y = test2(x)
        car(1).make = x;
        y = car;
    end
% 
y = test1('red');
y = test2('Mazda');
% 
car
```

edit2:
failed attempt:
[image]

Comment: Suggestion.  Instead of using `` characters to delineate your code, simply type it all out normally, then highlight all of your code and use Ctrl-K or Cmd-K if you're on Mac OS to automatically indent the code so that it can be visualized as a proper code block.  Use `` if you have a simple one-liner that is within a paragraph of what you're trying to explain.

Comment: lol no problem.  BTW, I forgot one small thing.  Try it now.  It works

Comment: lol no problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me.  However, you need to make sure that the above statements go into a **function** script and make sure you make `car` `global` in the workspace before running this function, and also do it **inside** the function too.  Doing `global car` in the workspace ensures that the variable is `global` then you must do it again inside the function script so that we maintain the same scope.

For example, this is what I have set up and I placed this in a file called `test_func.m`:

```
function test_func    

global car;   

function f1(x)
car.color = x;
end

function f2(x)
car.make = x;
end

f1('blue');
f2('audi');   

end
```

Once I have this set up, I just do this in the command prompt:

```
>> global car;
>> test_func;
>> disp(car);
```

I get this:

```
color: 'blue'
 make: 'audi'
```

Doing `global car` in the workspace allows the variable to be visible in every scope, then when I call the function, doing `global car` allows us to modify the `car` variable with its scope from the workspace and dynamically add the fields to make it a structure as you can see above.